# Nested Javascript for loops with break and label statements

Tags: javascript, break, labeled-statements

I'm kinda new to Javascript and currently going over the book Professional Javascript for Web Developers and I came across this code which uses a break statement to exit the current loop and jump to a label named outermost.

Now I understand what break and labels do but I can't wrap my head around why the value ends up being 55 at the end?

Ok so the for loop with var i will loop 4 times then at 5 it breaks out to label:outermost and same with j so the first iteration i = 4 and j = 4 and num = 2. I guess this part confuses me.. at what point does the code stop. My first instinct if I were to code this from scratch is to have an outside variable and set the condition on that. But with the below code I don't get where the control structure lies and the final value. Appreciate any help or to be pointed in the right direction, thanks.

```
var num = 0;

outermost:

for (var i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (i == 5 && j == 5) {
            break outermost;
        }
        num++;
    }
}
alert(num);
```

Comment: "the book Professional Javascript for Web Developers" --- a professional developer will never write a code similar to that.

Comment: @zerkms: The book is *professional Javascript* for *web developers* (not *professional* developers) ;)

Comment: both loops go from 0 to 10. That results in 10 * 10 loops. If i == 5 && j == 5 it ran 5*10 + 5 times. By the way, do not use labels and labelled break statements, that is a kind of very oldfashioned...

Comment: I agree with @zerkms. Although many programming languages support break with labels, it is a feature that really should never have been supported and which I have never had cause to use (nor do most programmers), as it can be easily avoided with clearer conditions on the loops or with subroutines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This nested loop is emulating an odometer. `i` is the 10's digit, `j` is the 1's digit. Every time the 1's digit changes, `num` is incremented; at the start of each iteration, `num` contains the odometer's value.

The loop stops when **both** `i` and `j` are `5`. At that point, the odometer would read `55`, and that's what is in `num`.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying, it's starting to make a little more sense but why is the outermost loop i in the 10's digit and the j is in the 1's digit?

Comment: I think I see what I'm missing - num++ belongs to the innermost loop so everytime j reaches a value of 10 it adds +1 to i?

Comment: It adds `1` to `i` every time the inner loop repeats, not just when it reaches `10`.

Comment: I see I think I got it... I know break statements are not a first choice solution in javascript but I wanted to make sure I understand exactly how it works in a nested for loop.

Comment: So basically what 55 represents is the number of times the outer loop and the inner loop has ran. So if we changed the if condition to 10 then we would get 100, change it to 4 we get 44 and so on. But does that mean var num is holding a reference for both those loops?

Comment: It's the number of times the inner loop has run. Every time the outer loop runs, the inner loop runs 10 times. Without the break, the outer loop would run 10 times, and the inner loop would run 10x10 times.

Answer (score 0):

When i was 0 to 4, the innermost loop is executed 50 times. When i = 5, the innermost loop is executed just 5 times until it reached `i==5 && j==5` and jumped out. So it's total of 55 times.